# Powershell not capturing perl's standard output

Tags: powershell, perl, strawberry-perl

I have the following simple script in powershell (say under `C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\tests\test.ps1`)

```
$counter = 0
while (1) {
    $counter++
    if ($counter % 2) {
        [Console]::Error.WriteLine("($counter) This is an error")
    } else {
        echo "($counter) Some output"
    }
    sleep 1
}
```

I want to programmatically invoke this script and capture its standard output and standard error into a file (say `C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\test.log`). For that I wrote the following powershell script:

```
$psi = New-object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$psi.CreateNoWindow = $true
$psi.UseShellExecute = $false
$psi.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
$psi.RedirectStandardError = $true
$psi.FileName = 'C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe'
$psi.Arguments = @('C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\tests\test.ps1')

$process = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$process.StartInfo = $psi

$logAction = {
    $time = Get-Date -Format o
    Add-Content 'C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\test.log' "($time)[$($Event.MessageData)]: $($Event.SourceArgs.Data)"
}

Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $process -EventName ErrorDataReceived -Action $logAction -MessageData "STDERR" >$null
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $process -EventName OutputDataReceived -Action $logAction -MessageData "STDOUT" >$null

$process.Start() >$null
$process.BeginErrorReadLine() >$null
$process.BeginOutputReadLine() >$null

$process.Id
```

The content of the `test.log` file is as expected:

```
(2018-12-05T15:00:45.7615056+01:00)[STDERR]: (1) This is an error
(2018-12-05T15:00:47.0119743+01:00)[STDOUT]: (2) Some output
(2018-12-05T15:00:47.9497710+01:00)[STDERR]: (3) This is an error
(2018-12-05T15:00:49.8253980+01:00)[STDOUT]: (4) Some output
(2018-12-05T15:00:49.8253980+01:00)[STDERR]: (5) This is an error
(2018-12-05T15:00:51.2008546+01:00)[STDOUT]: (6) Some output
(2018-12-05T15:00:51.8260768+01:00)[STDERR]: (7) This is an error
(2018-12-05T15:01:03.6269252+01:00)[STDERR]:
(2018-12-05T15:01:03.6269252+01:00)[STDOUT]:
```

But now comes the interesting part. I have the following perl script (say under `C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\tests\test.pl`) which I run in Windows using [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/), and which pretty much resembles the first powershell script in my question:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $counter = 0;

while (1) {
    $counter++;

    if ($counter % 2) {
        print STDERR "($counter) This is an error!\n";
    } else {
        print STDOUT "($counter) Some message\n";
    }

    sleep 1;
}
```

I also want to programmatically invoke this script and capture its standard output and standard error into a file. For that I change the second script in my question by updating the `$psi.FileName` and `$psi.Arguments` values to:

```
$psi.FileName = 'C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe'
$psi.Arguments = @('C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\tests\test.pl')
```

But now the content of the `test.log` file is not what I expected

```
(2018-12-05T14:14:53.9176561+01:00)[STDERR]: (1) This is an error!
(2018-12-05T14:14:55.7926306+01:00)[STDERR]: (3) This is an error!
(2018-12-05T14:14:57.9801317+01:00)[STDERR]: (5) This is an error!
(2018-12-05T14:15:22.2301618+01:00)[STDOUT]:
(2018-12-05T14:15:22.2301618+01:00)[STDERR]:
```

As you can see the standard output is not getting captured. I have absolutely no idea why is this happening and how can I solve it. Why is it not working for perl but it does for powershell? How can I get it to work with perl?

My powershell version is 5.1.17134.407 on a Windows 10 Pro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

STDERR is usually set up for auto-flush, STDOUT is not. Your code expects to receive every output line as it is written.

Try adding the following 2 lines to your Perl script after `use warnings;`

```
use IO::Handle;
STDOUT->autoflush(1);
```

Comment: `$| = 1;` will do the same.

Comment: @ikegami you are of course correct, but I prefer to write modern, readable code and not fodder for the Perl haters out there.

Comment: The equivalent would be `select->autoflush(1);` (but this ends up calling `select` three times and `$|` twice).